# Format date in yy-mm-dd

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

    $j(document).ready(function() {
        $j("#date").datepicker({
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
        });

        $j("#date").on("change", function () {
            var fromdate = $j(this).val();
            alert(fromdate);
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want to format date in `yy-mm-dd`. Its not working for me .  where i am going wrong any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: its show in mm/dd/yy

Comment: instead of `format`, try `dateFormat`

Comment: thank @RahulJain its worked for me